# How can I import a local binary package in a swift project?

Tags: ios, swift, rust

I have a project written in rust that exposes some operations through `ffi`. I want to create a wrapper in swift so the API looks nicer for the users of it.

The library binaries from rust are packaged in a `xcframework` format. So I have a folder structure like this:

```
_ out
___ CoreCrypto.xcframework
|______ ios-arm64
|____________ libcore_crypto_ffi.a
|____________ Headers
|__________________ core_cryptoFFI.h
|__________________ core_cryptoFFI.modulemap
|______ ios-x86_64-simulator
|____________ libcore_crypto_ffi.a
|____________ Headers
|__________________ core_cryptoFFI.h
|__________________ core_cryptoFFI.modulemap
```

Both module maps look like this

```
module CoreCrypto {
    header "core_cryptoFFI.h"
    export *
}
```

and here's my `Package.swift`

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.5

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "CoreCrypto",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v15)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "CoreCrypto",
            targets: ["CoreCryptoSwift", "CoreCrypto"]
        )
    ],
    dependencies: [],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "CoreCryptoSwift",
            dependencies: ["CoreCrypto"]
        ),
       .binaryTarget(
           name: "CoreCrypto",
           path: "out/CoreCrypto.xcframework"
       ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "CoreCryptoTests",
            dependencies: ["CoreCryptoSwift"]
        )
    ]
)
```

When I run `swift build` or I try to build it with Xcode it always fails to import the module, complaining that there's no such module `CoreCrypto`

What am I doing wrong that is causing it to be unable to resolve the module?

**Note:** I have very few experience with swift, so I might be doing something stupid there...